# How to permanently save swatches in illustrator cc 2018?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I save my swatches and every time I re-open Illustrator CC 2018 they disappear. Is there a way that I can permanently save my swatches so they don't disappear after exiting? I'm a bit new at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the swatches to reappear every time you open illustrator without having to manually open them there are two options:

**Make a new document profile:**

Create a new document on the New Document presets location
For Illustrator CC the default profiles are stored in...

Windows:

```
\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator [version] Settings\[lang]\x64\New Document Profiles
```

Mac:

```
/Users/[user]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator  [version]/[lang]/New Document Profiles
```

Save the swatches, brushes, color profiles etc that you want into this document.
Whenever you open a new document you will be able to choose a profile (under "more settings" in the new file dialog", and they will include your swatches. You can also edit the default profile and skip the choosing.

[image: Choosing profile in Illustrator]

**Make a palette persistent**
If you open up your swatch palette, and click on its menu, you can choose an option called "Persistent". If you do so, your palette will open up next time you open Illustrator.

[image: Persistent palette]

Answer (score 1):

The work-around I use is that I save the color into my CC Library. Then, while it might not be in the exact "Swatches" panel, it's available across different programs and I can still easily use it!

Answer (score 1):

Select your chosen swatches in the swatches palette, then click on the far left button on the bottom bezel of the Swatches Palette (Swatch Libraries Menu) and in the popup that appears, choose Save Swatches - this will save them as a local file in the OS-appropriate location for non-cloud retrieval.

Select your swatches

[image]

Click On Swatch Library Menu Button - choose Save Swatches

[image]

Default location should be correct for your OS - or you CAN choose custom location and then navigate to it each time you wish to load your own proprietary swatches libraries.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A third way to do it is:

Load a swatch from an Ai file.

With the Swatches panel opened, click in its menu and Load Swatches. Find the **.ai** file you want the swatches and load it.

More: I use a master file with a bunch of swatches, brushes, symbols and Graphic Styles. I just load them using their respective panels.