# How to have a custom Default Swatch Library in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to have my custom Swatch Library open up in the top left corner, rather than the default library?

I have colors and spot colors I use in almost all my files. I would like to have them, and a true 100% CMYK in my default swatch library.

Comment: Just use the Swatches panel to load that .ai file. It will bring the swatches from that file.

Answer (score 1):

Almost a duplicate of an existing question, but not quite... however the answers from the previous question will help you.

[How to permanently save swatches in illustrator cc 2018?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114427/how-to-permanently-save-swatches-in-illustrator-cc-2018)

Answer (score 1):

Open the document profile files....

Location may vary based upon operating system. Generally it's something like:

`Applications/Adobe Illustrator/Support Files/New Document Profiles/en_US/` containing files such as...

- Art & Illustration.ai
- Film and Video.ai
- Mobile.ai
- Print.ai
- Web.ai

## Back up these files before making any changes

If you edit *those files* and then save them to the same location that will change the startup files for new documents. You can do things such as add custom Brushes, edit the Swatches, change the Symbols or Graphic styles, etc.

Simply edit, and `Save As` to your desktop, then use File Explorer or The Finder to replace the existing, original, file (**AFTER you've backed up the original file**).

Then **relaunch Illustrator**. New documents should then reflect your changes.

Note that there is nothing which will edit *existing* files in the same manner. This only edits the "start" files for new documents.

---

Note that for versions *prior to Illustrator CC*, getting to the Document Profiles is much different. It can entail digging into the actual packaged application. Adobe didn't make the profiles so easily accessible prior to CC.

Comment: Another option is to make your own swatch library item and make that swatch window persistent from the hamburger menu. Thisway it would stay in use even on old files, atleast on your computer.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out! I found out how to make a swatch "Persistent" in the swatch panels on the right side, I was just hoping to change the default settings for the top left swatches.